# remove borders from grouped uitableviewcells when using static cells in storyboards

Tags: ios, storyboard

Is there a way to remove all boarders that cells in the group style have when using static cells in storyboards?

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

```
    cell.backgroundView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:cell.backgroundView.frame];// you can initialize with frame CGRectZero as well.
```

It works for me.

Comment: Thanks!  This was the only solution that worked for when the buttons can't be placed at the footer of the table.